# decrement value database if availability greater of request

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, eloquent

there is a way through query to scale the quantity of a product that can be double on the table because it comes from 2 different orders taking into account the customer's request and the quantity available for each product

For example, I have 2 wines with the same id_wine but coming from 2 different orders, so they have a different id_order, where they have as availability:

| id | id_wine | qty | id_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |

Total qty 5

If I order 5 wines, is there a way to be able to scale the counter of the first wine by 4 units and the last one to scale it from the other wine?

I can scale if I place single orders, so as long as the availability is> 0 I scale from the first, if <switch to 2 wine, but if I place an order with 5 wines all together, I scale only the first one, bringing the units to -1.

I'm doing this at the moment:

```
$scaleqty=warehouse::where('id_restaurant',Auth::user()->id_restaurant)
->where('id_wine',$wine_id)
->whereRaw('quantita_restante > 0')
->orderBy('id_order')
->first()
->decrement('quantita_restante',$request->quantita);
```

Comment: Please don't add an answer to your question by editing it in. If your question has been solved by an answer, you can accept it, if you solved the problem yourself you can [write your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if someone needs it in the future, I have solved my problem:

```
$selectwine=warehouse::where('id_restaurant',Auth::user()->id_restaurant)
->where('id_wine',$wine_id)->whereRaw('quantita_restante > 0')
->orderBy('id_order')
->get();
$qta=$request->quantita;
foreach ($selectwine as $key => $value) {
   if ($value->quantita_restante <= $qta) {
       $qtarest=$value->quantita_restante;                
       $qta=$qta-$value->quantita_restante;
       $value->decrement('quantita_restante',$qtarest);                
   }elseif($value->quantita_restante > $qta){
       $value->decrement('quantita_restante',$qta);
       if($qta=0){
          break;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can do it this way but if i were you i would get all the data and loop over it and decrement only the quantity it has in stock assuming you would validate the stock before performing operation.

```
$quantity = $request->quantita;

$stocks = warehouse::where('id_restaurant',Auth::user()->id_restaurant)
->where('id_wine',$wine_id)
->whereRaw('quantita_restante > 0')
->orderBy('id_order')
->get();

foreach($stocks as $stock){
 if($stock->qty < $quantity){
  $stock->decrement($stock->qty);
  $quantity = $quantity-$stock->qty;
 }
}
```

This is just for the part where the quantity of order is greater than the greatest quantity of stock in your database which you can check by ordering the data in descending order of quantity and check first and if it is greater than the requested order quantity you can subtract from that stock so you don't have to do this calculation.

```
$stock = warehouse::where('id_restaurant',Auth::user()->id_restaurant)
->where('id_wine',$wine_id)
->orderBy('qty','desc')
->first();

if($stock->qty > $request->quantita){
$stock->decrement($request->quantita)
}else{
  //code from above make sure to check you stop the loop once the request varaible becomes zero
}
```

Comment: Great, that's just the approach I've been using in the last half hour after thinking about it a bit, I'll update you if it works

Comment: friend thank you for the help it was fundamental to get to the solution, I made some changes and everything works, I added the solution to my question.